# Calling a REST Service using WebClient JAVA

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-webclient

I want to fetch daa from an API using WebClient but the issue is on the tutorial I am watching the call is being made on this URL https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com and on the WebClient methods he specified his URI ex. /comments or /todos /albums.
But the API I am going to use has this format https://exampleAPI.com/api/v1/example/numberExample/5?apikey=123-456-789.
How do I make an API call to this URL and to all the various URI in the URL with and how do I include the APIKey.
The response has this JSON Format

````
{
   "query":{
      "apikey":"**your-apikey**",
      "someId":"5"
   },
   "data":[
      {
         "data1":496,
         "data2":"20/21",
         "data3":1,
         "data4":48,
         
      },
    ```
````

Comment: What is stopping you from simply building the URI for each endpoint?

Comment: @Vinz
Yes i am about to do that It just didn't look like good practice to be honest that's why I was reaching out for help
Thank you for your reply